# Django Testing: No Matching Query even though it was created

Tags: python, django, database, orm, model

I am receiving the following error when I run `manage.py test`:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_pokemon_detail_view (pokedex.tests.test_views.TestViews)
Test the pokemon detail view and ensure the correct template was used
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/z/chbresser/pokedex/tests/test_views.py", line 32, in test_pokemon_detail_view
    response = self.client.get(reverse("pokedex:pokemon", args=[self.pokemon.id]))
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 517, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 332, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 404, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 485, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/z/chbresser/pokedex/views.py", line 23, in pokemon
    poke = Pokemon(poke_id)
  File "/home/z/chbresser/pokedex/pokemon.py", line 152, in __init__
    gender_obj = PokemonGenderRatios.objects.select_related('ratio').get(pokemon=self.id)
  File "/home/z/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 403, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
pokedex.models.DoesNotExist: PokemonGenderRatios matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which usually means that the database did not have a PokemonGenderRatios object in it, but I created it in the setUp function:

```
def setUp(self):
    """ Set Up for testing """
    self.pokemon = PokemonFactory(species__evolves_from_species=None)
    PokemonGenderRatioFactory(
       pokemon__species__evolves_from_species__evolves_from_species=None)

def test_pokemon_detail_view(self):
        """ Test the pokemon detail view and ensure the correct template was used """
        response = self.client.get(reverse("pokedex:pokemon", args=[self.pokemon.id]))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'pokedex/pokemon.html')
```

Does anyone know why it is erroring out? I tried running the test with `--verbosity 3` but it didn't give any more details on the test.

`views.py`:

```
@require_safe
def pokemon(request, poke_id):
    """ View for /pokedex/pokemon/<poke_id> """
    if int(poke_id) > 721:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('''<h1 style="text-align: center">Sorry, you have went to an \
                                       invalid page. :|</h1>'''
                                    '''<h1 style="text-align: center">If this was in error,
                                       contact admin@chbresser.com</h1>''')
    poke = Pokemon(poke_id)
    context = {'pokemon': poke}

    return render(request, 'pokedex/pokemon.html', context)
```

`factories.py`:

```
class PokemonGenderRatioFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    """ Factory for Pokemon Gender Ratios Model """
    class Meta:
        model = PokemonGenderRatios

    pokemon = factory.SubFactory(PokemonFactory)
    ratio = factory.SubFactory(_GenderRatioFactory)

class _GenderRatioFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    """ Private Factory For GenderRatios Model """
    class Meta:
        model = GenderRatios

    percent_male = '50'
    percent_female = '50'

class PokemonFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    """ Factory for Pokemon Model """
    class Meta:
        model = Pokemon

    identifier = 'Pokemon Identity'
    species = factory.SubFactory(_PokemonSpeciesFactory)
    height = 10
    weight = 10
    base_experience = 10
    order = 1
    is_default = False

class _PokemonSpeciesFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    """ Private Factory for PokemonSpecies Model """
    class Meta:
        model = PokemonSpecies

    identifier = 'Species Identity'
    generation = factory.SubFactory(_GenerationFactory)
    evolves_from_species = factory.SubFactory('pokedex.tests.factories._PokemonSpeciesFactory')
    evolution_chain = factory.SubFactory(_EvolutionChainFactory)
    color = factory.SubFactory(_PokemonColorFactory)
    shape = factory.SubFactory(_PokemonShapeFactory)
    habitat = factory.SubFactory(_PokemonHabitatFactory)
    gender_rate = 50
    capture_rate = 40
    base_happiness = 20
    is_baby = False
    hatch_counter = 2
    has_gender_differences = False
    growth_rate = factory.SubFactory(_GrowthRateFactory)
    forms_switchable = False
    order = 1
```

There are a few subfactories I didn't post but can if needed. I didn't want to make things unclear.

Comment: It will also be helpful to see the code in `test_pokemon_detail_view`.

Comment: Which test framwork are you using ? 
Are you sure setUp is correctly called by your class ? 

What if you test PokemonGenderRatios.objects.count() ?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I have added test_pokemon_detail_view

Comment: @JulienKieffer I am sure setUp is called because I have it printing a "Created xxx Object" debug message. It is Django's built in testing which uses unittest if IIRC. PokemonGenderRatios.objects.count() is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PokemonGenderRatioFactory` creates a new `Pokemon` for its foreign key by default. What you want is one that points to the very pokemon you just created:

```
def setUp(self):
    """ Set Up for testing """
    self.pokemon = PokemonFactory(species__evolves_from_species=None)
    PokemonGenderRatioFactory(
        pokemon=self.pokemon,  # <-- this should be necessary
    )
```

Comment: You're the man! That was it. I don't think that I would have ever found that unless I looked at `Pokemon.objects.count()` and saw that there was 2.